# xpath produces empty lists when split while using for loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to use xpaths to download data from a website and I experienced behaviour that I can't logically understand. The first one is the only variant that works and the rest product empty lists. Can someone please enlighten me what am I missing!?

```
def parse(self, response):
    for block in response.xpath("//a[@class='level clearfix']/@href").extract():
        print(block)
Output:

        /course/335725/comprehensive-german-duolingo-vocabulary/1/
        /course/335725/comprehensive-german-duolingo-vocabulary/2/
        /course/335725/comprehensive-german-duolingo-vocabulary/3/
        /course/335725/comprehensive-german-duolingo-vocabulary/4/
        /course/335725/comprehensive-german-duolingo-vocabulary/5/
```

Output: (for the below code blocks)

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]

def parse(self, response):
        for block in response.xpath("//a[@class='level clearfix']"):
            print(block.xpath("/@href").extract())

def parse(self, response):
    for block in response.xpath("//a[@class='level clearfix']"):
        print(block.xpath("href").extract())
```

EDIT: Each element I'm trying to extract is as the following, and I plan to join the href to a base URL and use a call back function to extract data from that page.

```
<a href="/course/335725/comprehensive-german-duolingo-vocabulary/1/" class="level clearfix">
    <div class="level-index">1</div>
    <div class="level-icon">                   
                <i class="level-ico level-ico-s  level-ico-plant-inactive"></i>
        <div class="level-status">
                Ready to learn
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="level-title">
        Basics
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that! I added the element from the webpage

Comment: "/@href" → "./@href" (or "@href")

Comment: @Gallaecio please add that as an answer, not a comment, since it is the correct solution to OP's question

Comment: I think I should find one of the many duplicate questions, as it is a rather common issue. I’ve seen duplicates this very week. But I find it hard to find them by search, and I don’t want to go through every question from last week :|

Comment: sorry guys! I did search for similar issues here and the code blocks that resulted in empty lists in my question are form those answers! :) Thanks for the help, they do work and surprisingly I never came across any examples extracting the parameters using the "." form i.e "./@href" !